# Accessing Window Mediator in Firefox SDK Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Why is `Serivces.wm` undefined, when I use Firefox Addon SDK (JPM), and the following code in `index.js`:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
const { Cu } = require("chrome");
let Services = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
  id: "list-tabs",
  label: "List Tabs",
  icon: "./icon-16.png",
  onClick: myTestFunc
});

function myTestFunc() {
  var windows = Services.wm.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");
  while (windows.hasMoreElements())
    iterateWindows(windows.getNext().QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow));
}
```

The error I get, when clicking on my addon button in Firefox:

`TypeError: Services.wm is undefined`

Any suggestions would be of a great help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is failing, perhaps it has something to do with the deprecation of the [chrome API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/chrome). You can access the browser windows using the exposed [high level window API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/windows#browserWindows).

The windows API page reports this example:

```
var windows = require("sdk/windows");
for (let window of windows.browserWindows) {
  console.log(window.title);
}

console.log(windows.browserWindows.length);
```